# What is this thing apparently attached to the bottom of this Caravelle's engine, and why is it there?

Tags: feature-identification, nacelle, sud-caravelle

This Caravelle 10B appears to have something mounted on, or stuck to, the lower surface of its No. 2 engine nacelle.

[image: there is something under this Caravelle's engine]

(Image originally by clipperarctic at [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/23344035@N03/6153753611/), via Russavia at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Finnair_Caravelle_(6153753611).jpg); cropped and annotated by me.)

Photos of other Caravelles do not show a something of this sort under *their* engines.

What *is* this thing, and why does this particular Caravelle (and not others) have it?